# Presenting Sheet reset the Selected Tab (SwiftUI)

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-tabview, swiftui-sheet

Presenting sheet from childView of tabItem rerendering the whole Windows Group. My TabView alrdy has a selection Binding. When I use Fullscreen Cover it work fine. and sheet work fine with NavigationSplitView on iPad too. I have Attached some of the snippets. Please give some Ideas.

```
.sheet(item: $selectedVoucher) {
// on dismiss action 
} content: { voucher in
VoucherDetailsView(voucher: voucher)
}
```

Here is my TabView

```
TabView(selection: $selection) {
ForEach([NavigationItem.home, NavigationItem.vehicles, NavigationItem.workshop, NavigationItem.wallet, NavigationItem.profile]) { item in
item.destination
.tabItem { item.label }
.id(item)
.tag(item)
}
}
```

My Child View is wrapped in NavigationStack

The result I want is Just show the sheet only , not re-render the whole WindowGroup just bcos sheet is shown. .fullScreenCover is working fine not messing up with the TabView.

Comment: What do you mean by "re-render the whole WindowGroup"? How can you tell that it is rerendered? Please show a [mcve].

Comment: show the code that can be compiled and executed, and produces your issue.

Answer (score 0):

`$selection` must be binded to some persistent object.

I don't see your full code, but try to update it as follows:

Instead of `@State var selection = …`  use:

```swift
@StateObject var model = ViewModel()

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selection = ...
}
…
TabView(selection: $model.selection) {
   ...
}
```